# Passing value in URL generates error in JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, xmlhttprequest

I'm using jQuery's `$.ajax()` to communicate with the server. I'm passing the value of a textbox which was copied from MS Word. So it may contain XML tags and that's the problem. If I'm passing the variable to URL:

```js
var url = "someUrl&param1=" + encodeURIComponent(val1) + "&param2=" + encodeURIComponent(val2)..."
```

I will receive the following error message in Firefox:

> not well-formed

and the following in IE:

> XML5610: Quote character expected. Line: 6, Column 20

But if I'm passing the value via AJAX's `data` property it is okay:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        'param1' : val1,
        'param2' : val2
        ...
    }
});
```

I will not have error message. But why is this happening? The same data is passed to AJAX. I tried to set the `contentType` and `dataType` but it is not working when I'm passing values in URL.

So how to avoid the error messages when passing values in the Url?

------ EDIT

- not working:

  ```
  transUrl = "/XMII/Runner?Transaction=some_Mii_transaction&Content-Type=text/xml" +
                                  "&Category=" + category +
                                  "&Text=" + encodeURIComponent(content) +
                                  "&Title=" + encodeURIComponent(title) +
                                  "&OutputParameter=OutputXML";
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: transUrl,
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function (result) {
          ...
          }
  });
  ```
- working:

  ```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: {
                  "Category" : category ,
                  "Text" : content ,
                  "Title" : title
          },
          url: "/XMII/Runner?Transaction=some_Mii_transaction&Content-Type=text/xml&OutputParameter=OutputXML",
          dataType: "xml",
          success: function (result) {
          ...
          }
  });
  ```

Generally both workarounds are working... problem happens only if `content` is copied from MS-Word into a textbox and may have "rich" xml-formatting

Comment: You're including `encodeURIComponent(val1)` in the string itself? Is that intentional? I would guess you should be concatenating it instead. I would suggest you use the latter method anyway (ie. providing `data` with an object) as it's better practice.

Comment: sorry, it is concatenated in my code... I was just hurrying...

Comment: Could you give a complete example of the working and non-working `$.ajax` calls.

Comment: Could it be the first `&` after `someUrl`, replace it by `?`

Comment: What are the values of `val1` and `val2`?